# Cherenkov radiation in Schwarzschild metrics

Tags: gravity, black-holes, cherenkov-radiation

As we know, a particle radiate if it's velocity greather then the speed of light in media (Cherenkov radiation). Also, we know the Schwarzschild metric acts on electromagnetic fields like media with $\epsilon=\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{00}}}$ (see Landau-Lifshits, volume 2). Thus, particle which is move with speed $v>c\sqrt{1-\frac{r_g}{r}}$ must radiate Cherenkov radiation. Are there any misconceptions?

Comment: The orbital velocity is **less** than $c\sqrt{1-r_s/r}$ for all $r \gt \tfrac{3}{2}r_s$, so I don't understand why you think orbiting particles would emit Cerenkov radiation. For $r \lt 3r_s$ there are no stable orbits precisely because the body can't move fast enough to sustain an orbit.

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes, thank you, of course, the orbital velocity is less than $c\sqrt{1-\frac{r_g}{r}}$, I lost sight of it. But what about hyperbolic velocity?

Comment: The orbital velocity will never exceed the speed of light. So for example if you fire a projectile at a black hole at speeds near $c$ it will slow down rather than speed up as it approaches the black hole.